# type mismatch; found : Int required: String when trying to persist the form data in play framework

Tags: scala, web, playframework

I have a model as follows:

```
case class User(username: String, email: String) {
  var id:Int = User.nextId
}

object User {
    protected var currentId = 0

    def nextId: Int = {
      currentId += 1
      currentId
    }
}
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
object Users extends Controller {

  val users: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, User] = new HashMap

  val form = Form(
      mapping(
          "username" -> text,
          "email" -> text
      )(User.apply)(User.unapply))


  def add = Action {
    Ok(views.html.users.add(form))
  }

  def save = Action{ 
     implicit request =>
        val user = form.bindFromRequest.get         
        users.put(user.id, user)
        Ok("contact saved")
  }
}
```

But when I compile the code my browser throws an error telling there is a miss match in the type that is accepted by the `users.put(user.id, user)`.

The error message looks as follows:

[image]

When I change the type of the id as string then it will work but I want to keep my id as integer and not string.

Is there any way I can achieve this. I am using play framework 2.11.1.

What is that I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I am new to play framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`users` is a map from `String` to `User`.

```
val users: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, User] = new HashMap
```

The `put` method expects a key of type `String` and a value of type `User`, but you tried to use it with a key of type `Int`.

You need to change your map to the type

```
scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, User]
```

or instead you could use a value of type `String` as key.

Comment: Oh yes I so stupid. Thank you very much. It did worked.